# Heroku App with Namecheap Domain Not Working

Tags: node.js, heroku, dns, namecheap

I have tried everything that has already been suggested on this site and others.

### The Normal Way

- Add my domain `website.info` to Heroku's "Domains and certificates".
- Change the CNAME record to `website.info.herokudns.com` with the host `www`.
- Leave the redirect record to be Host `@`, `http://www.website.info`.

**Result:**

"No Such App" comes up for Heroku.

### The WWW way

The same thing as normal, except I added `www.website.info` to Heroku and removed `website.info`.

"This site can't be reached. `www.website.info`'s server IP address could not be found."

### Adding through the CLI

Installing heroku cli to my Git Bash: `npm install -g heroku-cli`

I try `heroku domains:add website.info -a websiteapp`.

"Domain already added to this app."

Tried accessing it. Same thing: "No Such App".

### Removing the Redirect

Same thing as the normal way, just without the redirect.

"This website.info page can't be found" `HTTP ERROR 404`

---

I used to do this all the time when I was learning how to build web apps. Worked flawlessly. Did Heroku change something for free dynos? Do I need to run SSL or something?

At the very least, I can redirect the domain to the `website.herokuapp.com` domain, but I would rather not do that.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: No I have not. I gave up and moved it over to firebase hosting, which also gave me a headache but ended up working, and also got me a free SSL certificate too. Maybe after my event is done I will come back to this, unless someone else finds a solution.

Comment: If you do get around to trying this again, could you supply the output of: `$ heroku domains` and also paste in the configuration of `Domains > Details > Domain > Redirect Domain` and `Domains > Detials > Advanced DNS > Host Records`. I was experiencing similar problems as you have described, but managed to eventually work them out.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue and tried all the methods you have tried plus more. In the end how got my custom domain to work was to set my namecheap Domain settings to `Custom DNS`.

`elle.ns.cloudflare.com`

`rudy.ns.cloudflare.com`

From there i used the `www.customdomain.com` format on heroku and set the rest up on `Cloudflare` as follows:

On the DNS Tab

`Type  Name     Content             TTL  Proxy status
CNAME  www   myapp.herokuapp.com   Auto  Proxied`

On the SSL/TLS Tab select `Full`

On the Page Rules Tab

`If the URL matches:
 customdomain.com/`

`Then the settings are:
 Forwarding URL 
 301 - Permanent Redirect
 /www.customdomain.com`

After i applied those settings everything worked perfectly. I hope this can help anyone facing this issue in the future.